# How to solve this multi selection issues in android?

Tags: java, android, multi-select

This is my Multi selection code.

```
public class CheckableLayout1 extends ImageView implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout1(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        setForeground(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_select) : null);
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked())
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        return drawableState;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
```

It works in android nougat but not in any lower version of android. What is wrong with it?

Comment: logcat? errors? more info about what is not working?

Comment: you are using @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") without and alternative to old sdks.

Comment: Inside your gradle change :